# Emacs Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80 possibly related to TLS shenanigans

Tags: gnutls, list-packages

When I am trying to do `M-x package-refresh-contents` I get `Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80` stuck until I do `C-g`.
I tried to install a package and it didn't work through `M-x package-install *package_name*` and it didn't work, so I started to search for a solution. I can't find the exact command I ran, but it was related to TLS and something with the word "Normal" IIRC. After doing so, my connection to repositories stopped working. I checked and changed many times my package-list, this is my current init.el code snippet related to links to melpa etc:

```
(setq package-archives                                                                                                                                                                                     
      '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")                                                                                                                                                          
        ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")                                                                                                                                              
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

I also tested HTTPS connections, it works through eww and opens elpa.gnu link, giving me a list of packages, melpa.org site also works, but marmalade-repo is stuck in `Loading http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/...` . Not sure how to fix the emacs now, I also upgraded from the 26 version to 27, it didn't work. Currently using a workaround via using "Straight" package installation, but I want to try to understand what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: I believe you want `https` for *both* `gnu` and `melpa`, and furthermore that `marmalade` may no longer be active (I didn't think it was still running, and while the domain is valid, it seemingly doesn't have a current certificate).  You would rarely want to prefer `http` when `https` was supported.

Comment: Yeah, need to add the parenthesis in my first post, it's in place in my init.el. It looks like maybe deleting marmalade and adding s to http fixed an issue, at least refresh now works, but need to check if packages can be successfully installed.

Comment: Yes, it looks like melpa is indeed was the root of the problem (and possibly httpS). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't mark a comment as an answer, so I will copy the comment of phils to mark it as a solution.

"I believe you want `https` for *both* `gnu` and `melpa`, and furthermore that `marmalade` may no longer be active (I didn't think it was still running, and while the domain is valid, it seemingly doesn't have a current certificate). You would rarely want to prefer `http` when `https` was supported."

The working configuration is therefore:

```el
(setq package-archives                                                                                                                                                                                     
      '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")                                                                                                                                                          
        ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.  Thank-you.
Specifically, I added the line `(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")` to my `init.el`.    Actually a better way to set variables is with this line:
(custom-set-variables  '(gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3"))

I already had https for all my package archives, but apparently I was not
using TLS1.3.  So, when I would try to `M-x package-refresh-contents`, or simply U to upgrade, I was getting this error message:

```
Error retrieving: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents \ 
(error connection-failed "connect" :host "elpa.gnu.org" :service 443)
```

Anyway, adding that line to my init.el fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found I also needed the below:

gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3"

Edit:
I have since lost the site that I have found this. When I would try and issue a package-list-packages command it would hang and eventually time out. The person indicated that the packages site now requires TLS 1.3 and to add that line. Since then when I update my package list it does not hang.

I believe I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084969/emacs-listing-packages-error-in-process-sentinel

Comment: You mean I need to M-x it as S expression or to add it to init.el?

Comment: I added it in init.el as: (custom-set-variables
'(gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3") )

Comment: I have a feeling this was the expression I used initially, which caused issues in the first place. Maybe, using it caused problems with Marmelade.

Comment: You also needed this to do what exactly? Please expand your answer to explain what goes wrong without this.